# How To Make a JPanel visible after clicking a JButton on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

Here we go...My java application's login form has a option called forgot password..when I click that a panel should appear same time login JFrame goes back and keep as a shade window.that new panel come forward.

this.dispose();

this will close the default window is there any method to do that..keep default window open and goes back like a shade, a panel come forword

Comment: I think you guys understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Dont use .dispose() you only need to hide it.Use

```
.setVisible(false);
```

If you want to make it faded out you have to animate it.Use jDialog instead.And play a bit with opacity.Bud in that case dont put set visible to False.Or you wont see it at all.

On new component which you want to have over it

```
.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // this makes sure that you will see it on top of your main window
```

after you are done put it away with dispose if you dont need it afterwards.

Comment: how to work with JDialog can you give me an example related to my quiz

Comment: Its same as JFrame if you know how to use that one.Bud it also have method to set opacity thats why i use it to animate some of my stuff.It also have same methods so there is nothing to be afraid of

Comment: It same as JFrame but how to give an opacity to than I never work with this..how to call my Jpanel to visible one JDialog

Comment: Dont mix those two.I think you shoud stick rather to JFrame. Use myJFrame.setVisible(false); to hide it so you can show your over the top window.And then when you are done with all the things use myJFrame.setVisible(false)  // if you decide to animate it and want to play with opacity you have to run it on another thread concurrently with your main flow.Use myJDialog.setOpacity(0.5f) BUD! As i sayd in this case dont use setVisible(false) instead bring your another frame over the top of main window(secondWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true)) make sure you make it visible.

Comment: You shoud check some documentation to sharpen your skills with GUI.Before you start to animate any of this.If you just want to make it work keep it simple.Use JFrame.